# Unable to get data from a particular WCF Service Operation which is sending files in response

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have a WCF Service with many methods, two of which are transferring files. One is working correct, it sends 3 files as byte array in a single row. But the other one is sending a list of Database Rows, where each Row has one Docx File in it. When the WCF Client invokes this operation, it runs successfully on the Server side and the Rows are fetched from the database, but after it sends the response, the client receives the following exception:

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to
>   http://localhost/Service/Service.svc. This could be due
>   to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This
>   could also be due to an HTTP request context being  aborted by the
>   server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server l ogs
>   for more details. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected
>   error occurred on a receive.

The minimal code is listed below:

```
[DataContract]
public class Document
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public byte[] File { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int SchemaId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SchemaId")]
    public virtual Schema Schema { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<Document> GetDocuments(int schemaId);
}

public class Service : IService, IDisposable
{
    DbContext db = new DbContext();
    public List<Document> GetDocuments(int schemaId)
    {
        List<Document> docs = db.Documents.Where(d => d.SchemaId == schemaId).ToList();
        return docs;
    }
}

public partial class ServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<IService>, IService
{
    public Document[] GetDocuments(int schemaId)
    {
        return base.Channel.GetDocuments(schemaId);
    }
}

try
{
    ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IService");
    client.Open();
    List<Document> docs = client.GetDocuments(9).ToList();
    client.Close();
}
catch{}
```

In the WCF Client config file, I am using default values of `basicHttpBinding`. After I received this exception, I tried increasing `maxReceivedMessageSize` on the binding in client side, but still receiving the same exception.

Please suggest, how can I resolve this?

Comment: If your data sending longer than 90 sec - increase transferring and recieving time.  
[Binding timeouts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh924831(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Everything is yet on the same machine, it can't take even more than a second I believe.